# Two php applications on same server conflicts with .env configurations

Tags: php, environment-variables

My question is quite similar to this [StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42075542/two-laravel-applications-on-the-same-server-conflicting-with-one-another). But there was no proper solution for that.

I am using two php applications separately for front-end and back-end(API) on same server. There are **two .env files** separately for each. When there are DB configurations on both env files, when there is call from front-end to back-end, API supposed to use back-end .env file's DB configurations. Instead, it uses front-end DB configurations.

How can I prevent using front-end DB configurations?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two Laravel applications on the same server conflicting with one another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42075542/two-laravel-applications-on-the-same-server-conflicting-with-one-another)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I have mentioned that on my question. Answer is not there. It is more of a comment than an answer.