# Using curl_init() call other project on the same domain and server

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

I got problem about using use curl_init() on the same domain and server.
I have 2 Laravel projects on same environment run with xampp (window).
Project A is API use database name X(RDS)
Project B call API use database name Y(MySql)

## Example URL

Project  A ww.example/project_a/

Project  B ww.example/project_b/

## Problem

Project B use curl_init() call API from Project A for get data from database X(RDS), but Project A try to find database X in MySql(Project B connection) and then error.

I already tried to make both project run on different server it can work.
Do I have to config something?

Here .env of both

Project A

```
APP_NAME= A
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=XXXXXXXXXXXXX
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=rds
DB_HOST=rds_url
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=X
DB_USERNAME=xx
DB_PASSWORD=xx
```

Project B

```
APP_NAME_B= B
APP_ENV_B=local
APP_KEY_B=YYYYYYYYYYYYY
APP_DEBUG_B=false
APP_LOG_LEVEL_B=debug
APP_URL_B=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION_B=mysql
DB_HOST_B=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT_B=3306
DB_DATABASE_B=Y
DB_USERNAME_B=yy
DB_PASSWORD_B=yy
```

Curl

```
$curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "http://ww.example/project_a/booking-box/get-data-by-api",
        CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION => true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",          
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                    //"authorization: ",
                    "cache-control: no-cache",
                    "content-type: Application/json"
                ),
                ));
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
```

Error Because Project A can't find X in Mysql

```
 "SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'X' (SQL: select * from `...` where `...` = 1 limit 1)"
```

Also already try this but not work
[Two Laravel applications on the same server conflicting with one another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42075542/two-laravel-applications-on-the-same-server-conflicting-with-one-another)

Comment: what's the error ? where is your code using `curl_init()` ?

Comment: error from API side. It's just a error can't found table name... because database structure isn't same

Comment: how can we help you if we dont even know what's the error is exactly ? are we supposed to throw generic solution until one fixes your issue ?

Comment: Sorry I add some information

Comment: is your rds DB open for external connexion ? maybe there is an ip filter, try to connect to it via commands

Comment: **[You should not switch off `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` or `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER`](https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/10/certainty-automated-cacert-pem-management-for-php-software)**. It could be a security risk! [Here is how to get the certificate bundle if your server is missing one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32095378/1839439)